# Setting up parse.com local server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, server

I am following this instruction to setup the parse.com local server using mongodb:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

These three works fine:

```
$ npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
$ mongodb-runner start
$ parse-server --appId id --masterKey m
```

and I can see the parse server is running as per picture:
[image]

Then I am sending this simple json post request:

```
headers = {}
headers["X-Parse-Application-Id"] = "id"
headers["X-Parse-Master-Key"] = "m"
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
 local params = {}
commands_json =
                 {
                    ["score"] = 1337
                 }        
postData = json.encode(commands_json)
local params = {}
params.headers = headers
params.body = postData
network.request( "http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore","POST",getFeatured,params)
```

However, I get an error message in response {"code":1, "message":"Internal server error"} and with more details in the picture:
[image]

I haven't setup mongodb separately as I assume parse instruction includes that. I appreciate if someone would tell me what is wrong?

Comment: are you able to connect to mongodb at `127.0.0.1:27017` ? Please check the port at which mongodb is listening.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed two additional steps to make the parse server fully running:

Create this folder C:\data\db

Run mongod under C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin